# Find index of list item

Tags: python, regex

Im having some kind of mental block or something I think.
I have a list of dates and times that were extracted from larger list items using regex -

```
dates = [['2015-2016'], ['24/08/15'], ['0900-1045'], ['1045-1100'], ['1200-1300'], ['1300-1430'], ['1430-1450'], ['1450-1550'], ['31/08/15'], ['0900-1030'], ['1200-1300'], ['1300-1600'], ['07/09/15', '18/09/15'], ['21/09/15'], ['0900-1000'], ['1100-1200'], ['1200-1300'], ['1400-1530']]
```

Im unsure why this created a list of single item lists but it has,I have been trying to find the index of an item via

```
dates.index("0900-1045")
```

I have tried various search strings, the one above, "'0900-1045'" and ['0900-1045'] but what ever i do I get 'ValueError: "'0900-1000'" is not in list' or whatever text i used.
I would try searching for a partial string if possible but I dont know how.

Any suggestion why its not found ?

Stevo

Comment: No idea.  It works for me when I use `dates.index(["0900-1045"])`.

Comment: That's odd... I'm using Python 2.7. You ?

Comment: @zondo that's odd....:D two characters more

Comment: Ah, I think I have misunderstood the example code I found on here -

Comment: "Im unsure why this created a list of single item lists" -- you could've posted the code to fix that problem, then you'd be able to properly use that line of code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way that you've posted it, you're not going to find the entry because you have a **list of lists**. Therefore, you will need to search the list for a **list** not a **string**

```
dates = [['2015-2016'], ['24/08/15'], ['0900-1045'], ['1045-1100']]

dates.index(['0900-1045'])
```

Comment: man, don't kill the fun:( That was an ingenious comment from @zondo

Comment: @Mai just noticed your comment. Genius indeed.

Comment: Confusion between lists and lists of lists is correct, I was aware I had a list of lists but didnt realise that I couldn't search it in the same way as a normal list.

Answer (score 1):

`dates.index(["0900-1045"])` should work. If it doesn't, post your code.

To search for a partial match, you could do something like

```
import re
filter(lambda x: re.search(partial_string,x[1][0]), enumerate(dates))
```

to get list of matches with indices.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your 'dates' isn't a list of strings - it's a list of LISTS of strings (all those lists being of length 1). If you instead do
    dates.index(["0900-1045"])
the index is computed correctly. It would probably by best to rewrite your code so 'dates' is just a list of strings.

Answer (score 0):

If you really cant use a list as an index on whatever version of python you are running, you can do

```
[ x[0] for x in dates ].index('24/08/15')
```

or using a map:

```
map(lambda(x):x[0], dates).index('24/08/15')
```

but using a list as an index is the best by a long way:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the following -

```
Python 2.7.9 (default, Dec 10 2014, 12:28:03) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.

>>> dates = [['2015-2016'], ['24/08/15'], ['0900-1045'], ['1045-1100'], ['1200-1300'], ['1300-1430'], ['1430-1450'], ['1450-1550'], ['31/08/15'], ['0900-1030'], ['1200-1300'], ['1300-1600'], ['07/09/15', '18/09/15'], ['21/09/15'], ['0900-1000'], ['1100-1200'], ['1200-1300'], ['1400-1530']]
>>> dates.index("0900-1045")

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    dates.index("0900-1045")
ValueError: '0900-1045' is not in list
>>> dates.index(['0900-1045'])
2
```

As you said you are getting a list of single item lists then you should also search for the index of a list inside the dates list which should be done like this -

dates.index("a list")

Answer (score 0):

You should try dates.index(["0900-1045"]) as zondo's comment. This is because you have a list which has list elements. To get the position of the element in a list you should pass the actual element argument to the index method.
In your case the elements are lists itself, so pass the list.

Answer (score 0):

While the other answers have focused on finding the sublist in you list of lists that contain you target string, here is a method to flatten that list of lists so you can find the index of the string directly.

Given:

```
>>> dates = [['2015-2016'], ['24/08/15'], ['0900-1045'], ['1045-1100'], ['1200-1300'], ['1300-1430'], ['1430-1450'], ['1450-1550'], ['31/08/15'], ['0900-1030'], ['1200-1300'], ['1300-1600'], ['07/09/15', '18/09/15'], ['21/09/15'], ['0900-1000'], ['1100-1200'], ['1200-1300'], ['1400-1530']]
```

You can flatten the list of lists (each containing one string) to a flat list this way:

```
>>> dates[:]=[string for li in dates for string in li]
```

Now `dates` is a list of strings:

```
>>> dates
['2015-2016', '24/08/15', '0900-1045', '1045-1100', '1200-1300', '1300-1430', '1430-1450', '1450-1550', '31/08/15', '0900-1030', '1200-1300', '1300-1600', '07/09/15', '18/09/15', '21/09/15', '0900-1000', '1100-1200', '1200-1300', '1400-1530']
```

And your original `.index` will work:

```
>>> dates.index("0900-1045")
2
```

Answer (score 0):

You could enumerate, filter, and take the first match:

```
index = next(index for (index, date) in enumerate(dates)
             if "0900-1045" in date)
```